# Beep в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Издает звук с частотой 1 KHz. Длительность задается в регистре dx, пауза в bx. Процедура beep включает тут и выключает динамик. А что делает процедура sleep? По названию понятно, что это задержка, но весь процесс генерации сигнала происходит там. Помогите разобраться с этим кодом

```
beep    proc    near
push    dx     
mov al, 10110110b   
out 43h, al
mov al, 9ah         
out 42h, al
mov al, 4h      
out 42h, al     
in  al, 61h    
or  al, 00000011b   
out 61h, al     

pop bx      
call    sleep       

in  al, 61h          
and al, 11111100b   
out 61h, al     
ret
beep    endp

sleep   proc    near
xor ah, ah      
int 1ah     
add dx, bx     
mov bx, dx      
_wait:
int 1ah     
cmp dx, bx      
jb  _wait       
ret
sleep   endp
```

Comment: Процесс генерации выполняется таймером (8253/8254). А процедура sleep действительно организует задержку, после которой генерация звука тормозится.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Akina, в принципе можно было бы оформить в виде ответа.

Comment: @insolor imho не тянет. Да и полезность - нулевая.